# Tengo un problema al ejecutar en mariadb un while y más cuando quiero establecer las variables

Tags: mysql, mariadb, while

Cuando intento insertar estos codigo alfanumericos con mayúsculas en maridb me sale este error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4. Si alguien puede ver el error y ayudarme, gracias.

Código:

```
CREATE procedure yourdb.repeat_loop_example()
BEGIN

SET @counter = 0;

WHILE(@counter<=1000) DO

SET @cod = UPPER(substring(MD5(RAND()), -8));

IF (EXISTS(SELECT codigo FROM codigo WHERE codigo = @cod)) THEN
SELECT 'van: ' + @counter + 'insertados';
ELSEIF
INSERT INTO codigo (codigo, aplicado, tipo) VALUES (@cod, 0, 'PROMOCIÓN');
SET @counter = @counter + 1;
END IF;

END WHILE;

COMMIT;
END
```

Comment: Hola Irving, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Podrías ser tan amable de traducir la pregunta? También te invito a que leas el [tour] y [ask]

Comment: La pregunta debe ser traducida al Español

Comment: HI.. the official language for the site is spanish.. if you can translate this, great! if not, it will be close.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el error es que no has declarado las variables:

`@counter` y `@codigo` en base a mi experiencia primero debes declararlas y después usarlas:

```
Declare @counter as int;
Declare @codigo as int;

set @counter = 0;
SET @codigo = UPPER(substring(MD5(RAND()), -8))
```

Espero que eso te pueda ayudar, saludos.

Comment: Existe diferencia entre [DECLARE Variable](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/declare-variable/) y [User-defined Variables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/user-defined-variables/), es decir, `@\`counter\`` es diferente de `\`counter\``. Como indica la documentación, las [User-defined Variables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/user-defined-variables/) (`@\`counter\``) no pueden ser declaradas, ver [db<>fiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=28a47b3d7be216a1c38612173ba06f44).

Comment: @wchiquito  Entendido, gracias aprendí algo hoy :)

Answer (score 1):

El problema se encuentra en la estructura del `IF`, como se indica en la documentación:

> [IF Statement](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/if-statement/)
>
> Syntax
>
> ```
> IF search_condition THEN statement_list
>     [ELSEIF search_condition THEN statement_list] ...
>     [ELSE statement_list]
> END IF
> ```

necesita cambiar `ELSEIF` por `ELSE` ya que no tiene condición de búsqueda.

Adicionalmente algunas sugerencias:

- No es necesario usar [User-defined
  Variables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/user-defined-variables/)
  (`@counter` y `@cod`) cuando puede usar [DECLARE
  Variable](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/declare-variable/).
- Entiendo que en la línea:

  > `SELECT 'van: ' + @counter + 'insertados';`

  quiere obtener algo como el siguiente texto:

  > van: 4 insertados

  sin embargo, con la sentencia actual obtendrá lo siguiente:

  > ```
  > MariaDB [_]> SET @counter := 4;
  > Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
  >
  > MariaDB [_]> SELECT 'van: ' + @counter + 'insertados';
  > +-----------------------------------+
  > | 'van: ' + @counter + 'insertados' |
  > +-----------------------------------+
  > |                                 4 |
  > +-----------------------------------+
  > 1 row in set, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)
  >
  > MariaDB [_]> SHOW WARNINGS;
  > +---------+------+------------------------------------------------+
  > | Level   | Code | Message                                        |
  > +---------+------+------------------------------------------------+
  > | Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'van: '      |
  > | Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'insertados' |
  > +---------+------+------------------------------------------------+
  > 2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
  > ```

  por ello, necesita usar [CONCAT](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/concat/):

  > ```
  > MariaDB [_]> SET @counter := 4;
  > Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
  >
  > MariaDB [_]> SELECT CONCAT('van: ', @counter, ' insertados');
  > +------------------------------------------+
  > | CONCAT('van: ', @counter, ' insertados') |
  > +------------------------------------------+
  > | van: 4 insertados                        |
  > +------------------------------------------+
  > 1 row in set (0.00 sec)
  > ```
- ¿Por qué el `COMMIT` final?, ¿está dentro en una transacción?, ¿tiene establecida la variable [autocommit](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/server-system-variables/#autocommit) en cero (0)?.

Finalmente una prueba (con alguna variación para el correcto funcionamiento de la propia prueba):

```sql
MariaDB [_]> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `repeat_loop_example`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [_]> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `codigo`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [_]> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `codigo` (
    ->   `codigo` CHAR(8) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ->   `aplicado` BOOL NOT NULL,
    ->   `tipo` VARCHAR(10)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [_]> INSERT INTO `codigo`
    ->   (`codigo`, `aplicado`, `tipo`)
    -> VALUES
    ->   ('3771D128', 0, 'PROMOCIÓN');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [_]> SELECT
    ->   `codigo`,
    ->   `aplicado`,
    ->   `tipo`
    -> FROM
    ->   `codigo`;
+----------+----------+------------+
| codigo   | aplicado | tipo       |
+----------+----------+------------+
| 3771D128 |        0 | PROMOCIÓN  |
+----------+----------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [_]> DELIMITER //

MariaDB [_]> CREATE PROCEDURE `repeat_loop_example`()
    -> BEGIN
    ->   DECLARE `counter` TINYINT DEFAULT 0;
    ->   DECLARE `ONLY_FOR_TEST` TINYINT DEFAULT 4;
    ->   DECLARE `cod` CHAR(8);
    ->   WHILE(`counter` <= 5 /* 1000 */) DO
    ->     SET `cod` := CASE `counter`
    ->       WHEN `ONLY_FOR_TEST` THEN '3771D128'
    ->       ELSE UPPER(SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()), -8))
    ->     END;
    ->     IF (EXISTS(SELECT `codigo`
    ->                FROM `codigo`
    ->                WHERE `codigo` = `cod`)) THEN
    ->      SELECT CONCAT('van: ', `counter`, ' insertados');
    ->      SET `ONLY_FOR_TEST` := 0;
    ->     ELSE
    ->       INSERT INTO `codigo`
    ->         (`codigo`, `aplicado`, `tipo`)
    ->       VALUES
    ->         (`cod`, 0, 'PROMOCIÓN');
    ->       SET `counter` := `counter` + 1;
    ->     END IF;
    ->   END WHILE;
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [_]> DELIMITER ;

MariaDB [_]> CALL `repeat_loop_example`;
+-------------------------------------------+
| CONCAT('van: ', `counter`, ' insertados') |
+-------------------------------------------+
| van: 4 insertados                         |
+-------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [_]> SELECT
    ->   `codigo`,
    ->   `aplicado`,
    ->   `tipo`
    -> FROM
    ->   `codigo`;
+----------+----------+------------+
| codigo   | aplicado | tipo       |
+----------+----------+------------+
| 3771D128 |        0 | PROMOCIÓN  |
| 4454D080 |        0 | PROMOCIÓN  |
| 4EDEBFBA |        0 | PROMOCIÓN  |
| 4F97D07B |        0 | PROMOCIÓN  |
| A1A9B2DC |        0 | PROMOCIÓN  |
| A707C81E |        0 | PROMOCIÓN  |
| BFDBECE9 |        0 | PROMOCIÓN  |
+----------+----------+------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Ver [db<>fiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=ca4275b93e91ad0c86c4cd631ef9c38c).